# How to detect if a dynamic table overflows in a print page for manual page breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, page-break

I successfully applied page breaks between each table but I want to do it ONLY if the dynamic table overflows the A4 print page. How do I detect if my table has enough height to check when I should apply my page break?

This is how I use it:

```
    @media all {
        .pagebreak {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media print {
        .pagebreak {
            display: block;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
```

`<div class="pagebreak">`

Comment: page-break-after: auto;

Comment: @dandavis I've tried replacing the `always` to `auto` but it overflowed.